# Masonry lib don`t initialize with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Someone know something about this? 
thank you.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('.gallery-items');
        $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.colorista-item',
                    columnWidth: '.colorista-item'
                });
}
```

**Uncaught TypeError: $container.masonry is not a function**

Comment: Looks like the library isn't loading.  How have you confirmed that it is?

Comment: `code` var elemArticle = document.querySelector('.gallery-items');
   var msnryColorista = new Masonry( elemArticle, {
       itemSelector: '.colorista-item',
      columnWidth: '.colorista-item',
   });

when I load with JS all work fine, in this case lib loaded good.

Comment: @Xavier, can you post a fully working example the puts in evidence the problem? Otherwise we are just taking shots in the dark, like do you have `jQuery` included, or do you have `masonry` library included etc...